# Convert decimal hours to proper hours sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column which displays the sum of Loggedhours...One such record I have is 52.80 i.e(52 hrs and 80 mins), but thats the wrong way to display it.

It should be 53.20 (53 hrs and 20 mins). How can I accomplish it??

Plz Help.

Comment: Which database server do you use?

Comment: Does 52.130 mean 54 hours and 10 minutes? What's the column datatype?

Comment: sql server 2008..sorry abt that

Comment: @jarlh Yes that wud be right..datatype is decimal

Comment: I'd say use appropriate data types! Either interval type - if supported by SQL Server, or (not a very good idea) store hours and minutes in separate columns.

Comment: @jarlh I'll keep that in mind but for now I need a fix for this problem of mine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JacksonLopes, what is the precision and scale (especially the scale) of the decimal column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert decimal to time 6.80 =7.20 hrs in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902678/convert-decimal-to-time-6-80-7-20-hrs-in-sql)

Comment: SQL Server has a `time` type but neither `52.80` nor `53.20` are time values. Where do you want to display this value? Why don't you do the conversion on the client's side? Mixing up types leads to exactly the problem you are encountering now - someone made a similar conversion when storing the data but forgot to take aggregations into account. You need to modify the aggregation code or fix the "bad data" (according to the conversion)

Comment: PS, you may have much bigger problems. The aggregation problem means that all your data is meaningless - adding three `3.40` values will return `10.20` when 11 hours have passed.

Answer (score -1):

If the scale of the decimal column is 2 then the below solution helps:

```
declare @val decimal(18,2) =  52.80
declare @vval varchar(30) = cast(@val as varchar(30))
declare @p bigint = charindex('.', @vval, 1)

select 
        case when cast(hhmm.MM as int) >= 60 
                then cast(cast(hhmm.HH as int) + cast(hhmm.MM as int) / 60 as varchar(30)) + ':' + cast(cast(hhmm.MM as int) % 60 as varchar(30))
            else hhmm.HH + ':' + hhmm.MM
        end as T
from
    (select substring(@vval, 0, len(@vval)-@p+1) as HH, substring(@vval, @p+1, len(@vval)-@p+1) as MM) hhmm
```

If the scale is bigger than 2 the trailing zeros added automatically after conversion should be handled separately.

Comment: Why the downvote? I could use a reply so that I know what needs to be improved here..

Comment: You assume that `.` is the decimal separator, which will result in errors in databases with collations that use `,` like French, German, Greek etc. Also, going through so many string conversions and casts will hurt performance and is hard to maintain

Comment: Also, the problem seems to be that someone already did a similar conversion to store minutes in the fractional part but forgot about aggregations, so that summing rows resulted in meaningless data